# RPC semantics of gRPC

Tags: rpc, grpc, distributed-system

I am trying the find out what RPC semantics the gRPC library provides? Is it at-most once? Does it guarantee that an RPC call made by a client is not executed more than once on a server? I couldn't find this explicitly mentioned anywhere in the docs.

From what I understand, gRPC channels have an exponential back-off based retry mechanism of re-initiating TCP connections after transient failures. So, if a server fails after executing an RPC call but before responding, and later comes back up, a client RPC may end up getting executed twice.

Can someone throw more light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gRPC provides at-most-once guarantee by default. Things like retries and similar can change that, but they are opt-in. Another example of this is marking your RPC [idempotent or no-side-effects](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7945); you've explicitly told gRPC it is okay to replay the RPC.

gRPC may also replay when it is provided assurances elsewhere the RPC was not processed. We call this [transparent retries](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A6-client-retries.md#transparent-retries), which we're implementing now, and is based on HTTP/2 semantics where a server tells us the RPC was not seen by the service application.

gRPC's exponential back-off for *reconnecting* (not *retrying* RPCs) doesn't change the behavior. Normal RPCs fail outright when the connection is known-bad, but wait-for-ready RPCs that have not been sent are simply delayed until the connection is ready. There is no "replay" of the RPC involved; it is only sent once.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, gRPC channels have an exponential back-off based retry mechanism of re-initiating TCP connections after transient failures.

I think, that `GRPC` clients are pretty flexible, and you can try to disable retry attempts with https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#FailOnNonTempDialError

Though you'll have to care about retries on your own.